# Angular:How to pass scope data to directives

Tags: angularjs

just out of curiosity i like to know how to pass scope data to directives.

### sample code

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <ul ng-controller="MyController">
    <li my-directive ng-repeat="item in products">{{item.name}} &mdash; {{item.price}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {

$scope.products = [
    {
        'name' : 'Xbox',
        'clearance' : true,
        'price' : 30.99,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Xbox 360',
        'clearance' : false,
        'salesStatus' : 'old',
        'price' : 99.99,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Xbox One',
        'salesStatus' : 'new',
        'price' : 50,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'PS2',
        'clearance' : true,
        'price' : 79.99,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'PS3',
        'salesStatus' : 'old',
        'price' : 99.99,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'PS4',
        'salesStatus' : 'new',
        'price' : 20.99,
    }
    ]
})
```

my-directive code is not written. i like to know how many ways we can pass scope or controller data to directive so which i can manipulate from directives. say i like to pass item.price to directive. how many ways we can pass. discuss with sample code. thanks

Comment: `<li my-directive ng-repeat="item in products" ng-model="item">` through the `ng-model` directive. You will need to look at directive documentation for how to best manipulate the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways: 
HTML

```
<li my-directive price="item.price" ng-repeat="item in products">{{item.name}} &mdash; {{item.price}}</li>
```

Javascript

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    scope: { price: '=' },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope){
      console.log(scope.price)
    },
    controller: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
      console.log(ngModel.price);
      console.log(scope.price);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: i have couple of question for your code. why you define scope in directive ?
isolated scope property name has to be `price` ? here can we give different name ?

Comment: i am new in ng. this is first time i notice controller in directive. why and when people dclare controller in directive ?

Comment: can't we write if-else in link option to set css class to element ? this would be easy nah ?

Comment: what is meaning of  `require: 'ngModel',` ? if we do not write `require: 'ngModel' then what will not work?

Comment: can we set css to html element with angular service or factory ? if not possible then tell me what is lack there for which it is not possible by angular service or factory ?

Comment: if possible then would it be possible to discuss here with small sample code and with jsfiddle. thanks

Comment: Ok. Later i share with you a couple of examples.

Comment: thanks and please share ASAP when possible and do not forget. cheers

Comment: I have been working in a example for show a related concepts to the scope values in the directives and how share data in different directives attached at the same element. The example include testing for demostrate my arguments.
http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/VaQwpL

Answer (score 1):

You can define your directive's scope like below, where `'='` means that the binding is two way.  You probably also want to include `transclude: true`, since your directive appears to wrap other elements, although you'll likely be able to get rid of that (see below).

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {
            name: '=',
            price: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then, you'll call you directive like this:

```
<li my-directive ng-repeat="item in products" price="item.price" name = "item.name"></li>
```

Because you pass in `name` and `price`, you won't need to the values inside the `li`.

Comment: i have couple of question for your code. what is transclude: true ?
what is the meaning of transclude = true or false? in what kind of situation people work with transclude: true or false?

Comment: where i have to put this file my-directive.html. what would be the location?

Comment: what code i need to write inside my-directive.html file ?

Comment: can we set css to html element with angular service or factory ? if not possible then tell me what is lack there for which it is not possible by angular service or factory ?